# Copying files to clipboard and then pasting them into their original folder does not work

Tags: delphi, clipboard, copy-paste

I've got a puzzling situation. I am using the following code in Delphi to copy a list of files to the clipboard;

```
procedure TfMain.CopyFilesToClipboard(FileList: string);
const
  C_UNABLE_TO_ALLOCATE_MEMORY = 'Unable to allocate memory.';
  C_UNABLE_TO_ACCESS_MEMORY = 'Unable to access allocated memory.';
var
  DropFiles: PDropFiles;
  hGlobal: THandle;
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := Length(FileList);
  hGlobal := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_SHARE or GMEM_MOVEABLE or
  GMEM_ZEROINIT, SizeOf(TDropFiles) + ((iLen + 2) * SizeOf(Char)));
  if (hGlobal = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create(C_UNABLE_TO_ALLOCATE_MEMORY);
  try DropFiles := GlobalLock(hGlobal);
    if (DropFiles = nil) then raise Exception.Create(C_UNABLE_TO_ACCESS_MEMORY);
    try
      DropFiles^.pFiles := SizeOf(TDropFiles);
      DropFiles^.fWide := True;
      if FileList <> '' then
        Move(FileList[1], (PByte(DropFiles) + SizeOf(TDropFiles))^,
      iLen * SizeOf(Char));
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
    end;
    Clipboard.SetAsHandle(CF_HDROP, hGlobal);
  except
    GlobalFree(hGlobal);
  end;
end;
```

(This seems to be a popular piece of code on the internet)

Using my application, once the files are copied to the clipboard, I can use Windows Explorer to paste them into every other folder, EXCEPT the folder where the file originally came from! I was expecting it to behave just like a normal Windows copy (i.e. on paste it should create a file with postfix of '-Copy') but this doesn't seem to work. Any clues?

Comment: Could you share your "Paste" code too? The copy code is seemingly ok.

Comment: @mg30rg: there is no "paste" code as he is using explorer to paste the files?

Comment: @whosrdaddy - I don't really see what is the point of his code then. I thought he is using Explorer as a reality check device to see if the file list is actually copied.

Comment: @dudeinmoon - So you wish to use explorer to paste your file? And if you are and it fails, **how exactly does it fail?** Does it throw an _error/exception_ message? Does it paste files which are meanwhile manually deleted? We can't help if you don't provide more information.

Comment: @mg30rg - hello, yes I'm using Windows Explorer to paste the file (I'm trying to create a simple clipboard file manager). It fails in the way that when you go to the folder and right click paste, nothing happens. If I go to another folder and right click paste, it works

Comment: @dudeinmoon - If I were you I would try to debug the phenomenon by introducing a temporary paste code and capture the response of the paste API to know what is the problem of windows with your paste operation.

Comment: @dudeinmoon - You see... you cant debug an error you can't see.

Comment: @dudeinmoon - Could it be failing because the file you copied into the clipboard is still open & therefore locked (i.e. the system isn't going to let you overwrite an open file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not able to get Windows Explorer to paste into the source folder when the only clipboard format available is `CF_HDROP`.  However, if the filenames are provided in an `IDataObject` instead, it works fine.

If all of the files are from the same source folder, you can retrieve the `IShellFolder` of the source folder and query it for child PIDLs for the individual files, then use `IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf()` to get an `IDataObject` that represents the files.  Then use `OleSetClipboard()` to put that object on the clipboard.  For example:

```
uses
  System.Classes, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.ActiveX, Winapi.Shlobj, Winapi.ShellAPI, System.Win.ComObj;

procedure CopyFilesToClipboard(const Folder: string; FileNames: TStrings);
var
  SF: IShellFolder;
  PidlFolder: PItemIDList;
  PidlChildren: array of PItemIDList;
  Eaten: UINT;
  Attrs: DWORD;
  Obj: IDataObject;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (Folder = '') or (FileNames = nil) or (FileNames.Count = 0) then Exit;
  OleCheck(SHParseDisplayName(PChar(Folder), nil, PidlFolder, 0, Attrs));
  try
    OleCheck(SHBindToObject(nil, PidlFolder, nil, IShellFolder, Pointer(SF)));
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(PidlFolder);
  end;
  SetLength(PidlChildren, FileNames.Count);
  for I := Low(PidlChildren) to High(PidlChildren) do
    PidlChildren[i] := nil;
  try
    for I := 0 to FileNames.Count-1 do
      OleCheck(SF.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PChar(FileNames[i]), Eaten, PidlChildren[i], Attrs));
    OleCheck(SF.GetUIObjectOf(0, FileNames.Count, PIdlChildren[0], IDataObject, nil, obj));
  finally
    for I := Low(PidlChildren) to High(PidlChildren) do
    begin
      if PidlChildren[i] <> nil then
        CoTaskMemFree(PidlChildren[i]);
    end;
  end;
  OleCheck(OleSetClipboard(obj));
  OleCheck(OleFlushClipboard);
end;
```

**Update:** If the files are in different source folders, you can use the [`CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST) format:

```
uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.ActiveX, Winapi.Shlobj, Winapi.ShellAPI, System.Win.ComObj, Vcl.Clipbrd;

{$POINTERMATH ON}

function HIDA_GetPIDLFolder(pida: PIDA): LPITEMIDLIST;
begin
  Result := LPITEMIDLIST(LPBYTE(pida) + pida.aoffset[0]);
end;

function HIDA_GetPIDLItem(pida: PIDA; idx: Integer): LPITEMIDLIST;
begin
  Result := LPITEMIDLIST(LPBYTE(pida) + (PUINT(@pida.aoffset[0])+(1+idx))^);
end;

var
  CF_SHELLIDLIST: UINT = 0;

type
  CidaPidlInfo = record
    Pidl: PItemIDList;
    PidlOffset: UINT;
    PidlSize: UINT;
  end;

procedure CopyFilesToClipboard(FileNames: TStrings);
var
  PidlInfo: array of CidaPidlInfo;
  Attrs, AllocSize: DWORD;
  gmem: THandle;
  ida: PIDA;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (FileNames = nil) or (FileNames.Count = 0) or (CF_SHELLIDLIST = 0) then Exit;
  SetLength(PidlInfo, FileNames.Count);
  for I := Low(PidlInfo) to High(PidlInfo) do
    PidlInfo[I].Pidl := nil;
  try
    AllocSize := SizeOf(CIDA)+(SizeOf(UINT)*FileNames.Count)+SizeOf(Word);
    for I := 0 to FileNames.Count-1 do
    begin
      OleCheck(SHParseDisplayName(PChar(FileNames[I]), nil, PidlInfo[I].Pidl, 0, Attrs));
      PidlInfo[I].PidlOffset := AllocSize;
      PidlInfo[I].PidlSize := ILGetSize(PidlInfo[I].Pidl);
      Inc(AllocSize, PidlInfo[I].PidlSize);
    end;
    gmem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, AllocSize);
    if gmem = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      ida := PIDA(GlobalLock(gmem));
      if ida = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
      try
        ida.cidl := FileNames.Count;
        ida.aoffset[0] := SizeOf(CIDA)+(SizeOf(UINT)*FileNames.Count);
        HIDA_GetPIDLFolder(ida).mkid.cb := 0;
        for I := 0 to FileNames.Count-1 do
        begin
          ida.aoffset[1+I] := PidlInfo[I].PidlOffset;
          Move(PidlInfo[I].Pidl^, HIDA_GetPIDLItem(ida, I)^, PidlInfo[I].PidlSize);
        end;
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(gmem);
      end;
      Clipboard.SetAsHandle(CF_SHELLIDLIST, gmem);
    except
      GlobalFree(gmem);
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    for I := Low(PidlInfo) to High(PidlInfo) do
      CoTaskMemFree(PidlInfo[I].Pidl);
  end;
end;

initialization
  CF_SHELLIDLIST := RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST);
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure CopyFilesToClipboard(FileNames: TStrings);
var
  Pidls: array of PItemIdList;
  Attrs: DWORD;
  I: Integer;
  obj: IDataObject;
begin
  if (FileNames = nil) or (FileNames.Count = 0) then Exit;
  SetLength(Pidls, FileNames.Count);
  for I := Low(Pidls) to High(Pidls) do
    Pidls[I] := nil;
  try
    for I := 0 to FileNames.Count-1 do
      OleCheck(SHParseDisplayName(PChar(FileNames[I]), nil, Pidls[I], 0, Attrs));
    OleCheck(CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray(nil, FileNames.Count, PItemIDList(Pidls), obj));
  finally
    for I := Low(Pidls) to High(Pidls) do
      CoTaskMemFree(Pidls[I]);
  end;
  OleCheck(OleSetClipboard(obj));
  OleCheck(OleFlushClipboard);
end;
```

However, I found that Windows Explorer will sometimes but not always allow `CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST` to be pasted into the source folder of a referenced file.  I don't know what criteria is preventing Windows Explorer from pasting.  Maybe some kind of permissions issue?

You should take Microsoft's advice:

[Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx)

> Include as many formats as you can support. You generally do not know where the data object will be dropped. This practice improves the odds that the data object will contain a format that the drop target can accept.

Comment: Sorry, I also meant to add that the collection of files being copied could be from multiple source folders.

Comment: @dude - A normal Windows copy doesn't do that.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: a user cannot select multiple files from different folders at the same time, but an application can, and Windows Explorer is able to paste files from multiple sources.

Comment: Thanks for that Remy, this works just perfectly. I haven't come across any permission problems yet (perhaps because my application has a manifest to request administrator rights?). Regardless, I shall keep an eye out for this. Much appreciate your help.